# Fill area, limited by lines and circle

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

How to fill area, limited by circle and (for example) 3 lines? as you can see at the picture. can I use `GraphicsPath` for it? if so, how to determine, that only area inside circle and lines need to be filled, not the area inside circle and outside the lines?

[image]

Comment: _"can i use GraphicsPath for it?"_ - try it and see

Comment: What have you tried? What code did you write? What did that code do? How was that different from what you wanted? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly the answers to those questions. IMHO, while you can probably get `GraphicsPath` to accomplish this, given the "composited shapes" aspect of the diagram, you are probably better off using `Region` objects, i.e. creating the underlying shapes and intersecting them, and then filling the region.

Comment: Don't post answers in the question body.  There is an answer box you can use below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i found the solution, first i need to extend my rectangle area and then intersect it by circle.

so the code is:

```
GraphicsPath gr = new GraphicsPath();
gr.AddLines(pointsArray);
Region reg = new Region(gr);
GraphicsPath gr2 = new GraphicsPath();
gr2.AddEllipse(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleW, circleH);
reg.Intersect(gr2);
e.Graphics.FillRegion(brush, reg); // e is PaintEventArgs
```